# Trying to get TOP 10 products per sales channel

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have found some answers on this, but nothing helped me here. I need a query to find the top 10 products for every sales channel (5 in total) within a month. I've tried my luck with a monstrous union all query, but I don't get the results I need. (I think the query I've written isn't the best, anyway...)

```
SELECT a.SKU, a.ProductName, b.SalesChannel, sum(a.PurchasedQuantity) as pq
FROM all_all_orders_items a
INNER JOIN all_all_orders b ON b.AmazonOrderID = a.AmazonOrderID
WHERE b.SalesChannel = 1 AND b.PurchaseDate  BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
GROUP BY a.SKU, b.SalesChannel
UNION ALL
SELECT a.SKU, a.ProductName, b.SalesChannel, sum(a.PurchasedQuantity) as pq
FROM all_all_orders_items a
INNER JOIN all_all_orders b ON b.AmazonOrderID = a.AmazonOrderID
WHERE b.SalesChannel = 2 AND b.PurchaseDate  BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
GROUP BY a.SKU, b.SalesChannel
UNION ALL
SELECT a.SKU, a.ProductName, b.SalesChannel, sum(a.PurchasedQuantity) as pq
FROM all_all_orders_items a
INNER JOIN all_all_orders b ON b.AmazonOrderID = a.AmazonOrderID
WHERE b.SalesChannel = 3 AND b.PurchaseDate  BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
GROUP BY a.SKU, b.SalesChannel
UNION ALL
SELECT a.SKU, a.ProductName, b.SalesChannel, sum(a.PurchasedQuantity) as pq
FROM all_all_orders_items a
INNER JOIN all_all_orders b ON b.AmazonOrderID = a.AmazonOrderID
WHERE b.SalesChannel = 4 AND b.PurchaseDate  BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
GROUP BY a.SKU, b.SalesChannel
UNION ALL
SELECT a.SKU, a.ProductName, b.SalesChannel, sum(a.PurchasedQuantity) as pq
FROM all_all_orders_items a
INNER JOIN all_all_orders b ON b.AmazonOrderID = a.AmazonOrderID
WHERE b.SalesChannel = 5 AND b.PurchaseDate  BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
GROUP BY a.SKU  , b.SalesChannel
ORDER BY pq DESC LIMIT 10
```

What would be the best way to get the results without querying the db 5 times?

Right now I only get the overall best products - but not sales channel specific...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.SKU, A.ProductName, A.SalesChannel, A.pq
FROM (SELECT A.SKU, A.ProductName, A.SalesChannel, A.pq, 
             IF(@SalesChannel = @SalesChannel:=A.SalesChannel, @RowId:=@RowId + 1, @RowId:=1) AS RowNum
      FROM (SELECT a.SKU, a.ProductName, b.SalesChannel, SUM(a.PurchasedQuantity) as pq
            FROM all_all_orders_items a
            INNER JOIN all_all_orders b ON b.AmazonOrderID = a.AmazonOrderID
            WHERE b.SalesChannel IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND b.PurchaseDate  BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
            GROUP BY a.SKU, b.SalesChannel
            ORDER BY b.SalesChannel, pq DESC
          ) AS A, (SELECT @SalesChannel:=0, @RowId:=1) AS B
      ORDER BY A.SalesChannel, A.pq DESC
     ) AS A 
WHERE A.RowNum <= 10
ORDER BY A.SalesChannel, A.RowNum;
```

Comment: Hi @Saharsh Shah..nice answer. if you don't mind I have one question for you. How did you know about table structure? only from given query by PO?

Comment: also I am not getting this condition. `@SalesChannel = @SalesChannel:=A.SalesChannel` can you help me to understand this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe query of this kind could be useful:

```
SELECT 
   b.SalesChannel, a.SKU, a.ProductName, b.SalesChannel, sum(a.PurchasedQuantity) as pq
FROM 
   all_all_orders_items a
   INNER JOIN all_all_orders b ON b.AmazonOrderID = a.AmazonOrderID
WHERE 
   b.SalesChannel IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND b.PurchaseDate  BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
GROUP BY 
   b.SalesChannel, a.SKU, b.SalesChannel
ORDER BY
   b.SalesChannel ASC, pq DESC LIMIT 50
```

I hope it may help in any way